# Myeclipse deployment issue for web module dependent java jars

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse

I am using WAS 8, in the deployment folder, I just need to get the dependent java jar projects under the x.war-> web-inf-> lib, .

This can be done easily in RAD using j2ee module dependencies-> web library tab. How to do this in Myeclipse?

I disabled the deployment assembly mapping and tried many options in Myeclipse but seems like all have same result..

Eclipse indigo some how deploys the dependent java jar projects under the x.war-> web-inf-> lib.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Dependent projects are deployed in the manner specified in the project properties (or the workspace preferences). Select the project, right click then go to Properties->MyEclipse->Web and select the Deployment tab. You can specify here how dependent projects are deployed and how exported jars from dependent projects are deployed, among other things.